# XML deserialization System.InvalidOperationException” the <Objects xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Since 2 days I can't deserialize XML file. I have tried lots of different ideas but still with no success. I get an error when i deserialize xml file called phone.xml on 1, 40. I thought it might be a problem with missing namespace in brackets with [XmlElement("id")] but notching changed. I copied different deserialization ideas same. No succes. Additionally I can't even convert this xml with any converter but i am sure it is correct. Help

jpeg example of xml structure inside link

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


public class OrderedItem
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id;
    [XmlElement("username")]
    public string username;
    [XmlElement("phoneType")]
    public string phoneType;
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string value;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program t = new Program();

        t.DeserializeObject("phone.xml");
    }

    private void DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with TextReader");

        XmlSerializer serializer =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

        OrderedItem i;


    i = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Console.Write(
            i.id + "\t" +
            i.username + "\t" +
            i.phoneType + "\t" +
            i.value + "\t");
    }
}
```

XML example

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Objects>
    <Object>
      <Property Name="id"></Property>
      <Property Name="username">JLOCK0</Property>
      <Property Name="phoneType">phone1</Property>
      <Property Name="value">346-209-9609</Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
      <Property Name="id"></Property>
      <Property Name="username">JLOCK0</Property>
      <Property Name="phoneType">phone2</Property>
      <Property Name="value">(478) 8085400</Property>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
```

Comment: Yes.  You should try serializing your `OrderedItem` to XML, you will see the result doesn't match your current XML - in fact they should be quite different.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RZj5A.  For one thing the XML contains a list of objects, not a single object.  For another, the property name `<Property ...>` does not correspond to any of your c# property names.

Comment: @dbc The problem is that i can't serialize it. I mean i will get data like this with missing stuff and I have to use as it is

Comment: OK.  That wasn't an answer, just a comment.  The point of the comment was that you can debug **de**serialization problems by serializing and comparing what you wrote with what you need to read.

Comment: Path "phone.xml" points to the current application folder. Check that the file with this name is correct in the output directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Objects
{
    [XmlElement("Object")]
    public OrderedItem[] Items;
}

public class OrderedItem
{
    [XmlElement("Property")]
    public Property[] Properties;
}

public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Objects));

using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    var objects = (Objects)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

    foreach (var item in objects.Items)
    {
        foreach (var prop in item.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " " + prop.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed advices above but still get an Exception 1,40 

> XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 40.

Comment: @Asumuri - This code works with you xml. Period.

Comment: I copied example xml from here and i get same error. I found that it might be sometching with encoding but not sure what have to be added

Comment: @Asumuri - The encoding is specified directly in xml: utf-8. Save the file in this encoding.

Comment: When I changed encoding to utf-16 everytching worked fine but what to do in code or how to rewrite XML from code perspective to read files like this

Comment: @Asumuri - don't ask in the comments. Create new topic for new question.